# Visual Studio 2015 not finding Visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015

My visual studio 2015 cannot build 2010 platform toolsets. It says:

> The build tools for Visual Studio 2010 (v100) cannot be found. To
>   build using the Visual Studio 2015 (v140) build tools, either click
>   the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Upgrade
>   Solution...". Install Visual Studio 2010 (v100) to build using the
>   Visual Studio 2010 (v100) build tools.

I do not want to upgrade my project or switch the toolset. I have visual studio 2010 installed. It builds the 2012 projects inside visual studio 2015 fine. 2012 also finds the 2010 build tools and builds 2010 projects fine.

Is there a visual studio setting where I can point it to the Visual Studio 2010 directory so that it correctly finds the build tools?

I have tried reinstalling 2010, 2012 and 2015 in that order.

tldr; Visual studio 2015 wont build 2010 projects even though I have visual 2010 installed.

Comment: Comment on downvote?

Comment: I had a similar issue recently. I can't find my notes on it right now, but I think the trick is to re-install VS 2010.

Comment: What project type are you building? class library, windows forms, etc?

Comment: A bunch of different things, dlls, libs, exe's. No windows forms though.

Comment: You need to change your toolset. This thread may help, its from VS2012, but might be relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15453629/use-visual-studio-2012-and-compile-with-older-platform-toolset

Comment: My Toolset is already on VS2010. As I said it is working in 2012 already.

Comment: Compare your machine with what you see in the "How does it work" section of [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx).  If these two files cannot be found then you get this error.

Comment: Reinstalling did not work.

Comment: @marsh Did you solve it?

Comment: No, I have tried the suggestions with no avail.

Comment: On a random guess: Have you also enabled the xp support when installing VS2015? I don't know, why this should make a difference, but maybe there exist some strange dependencies for older toolsets

Comment: This mainly looks problem of build tools scripts  [A] Please install **WindowsSDK** (NOT the latest one)   [B] check files in folder C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\VXXX\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\vxxx. resolve variable references.

Comment: Can you test/debug the program in my anwser to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447742/list-available-platform-toolsets (change the project path to your project's path) and check what it says? You're probably missing some .target files, or directories

Comment: OK weirdly enough I have another solution building 2010 projects fine. It just seems to be solution? When selecting 2010 it says not installed on one solution but not the other?

Comment: Check my earlier comment. Available platform is defined per project.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Build' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?). Could you provide full source instead of a snippet? I am not a c# developer and am unsure of what additional includes / setup I need.

Comment: @marsh - You need to add a reference to `Microsoft.Build` to be able to compile. PS: when you comment to someone, please make sure you use @<user> to make sure the user gets notified. I wasn't aware of your comment until I checked this post again.

Comment: @Simon Mourier I tried the Microsoft.Build already I still get that error.

Comment: @marsh - Maybe you're confusing add reference with add using statement? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx the thing is MsBuild used in that tool is the build platform also used for C++ projects, so it's quite central now. And running the tool from VS is somewhat different than running it from command line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install this service pack: https://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2015-update2-vs

Fixed the issue for me. Released March 3, 2016 so it was unavailable at the time of posting.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this documentation from microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770576.aspx), the toolset is a per-project setting. So you need to change it for all of your VS2010 projects inside VS2015.

> **To change the project toolset**
>
> 1. In Visual Studio, in Solution Explorer, open the shortcut menu for
>      your project (not for your solution) and then choose Properties to
>      open your project Property Pages dialog box.
> 2. In the Property Pages dialog box, open the Configuration drop-down
>      list and then select All Configurations.
> 3. In the left pane of the dialog box, expand Configuration Properties
>      and then select General.
> 4. In the right pane, select Platform Toolset and then select the toolset
>      you want from the drop-down list. For example, if you have installed
>      the Visual Studio 2010 toolset, select Visual Studio 2010 (v100) to
>      use it for your project.
> 5. Choose the OK button.

does that help?

Comment: I am aware of that, but for one solution it does not detect that visual studio 2010 is installed but for another it does. See: http://imgur.com/a/don5h

Comment: It not helped me too